# Execute command on reattaching byobu | screen | tmux session

Tags: screen, byobu, tmux

Can I automatically execute a command on reattaching a detached byobu (screen or tmux) session?

Every time I login, `/etc/motd` is displayed. Since I hardly ever log out and in, I'd like to have the same functionality when reattaching to my detached session. This could be a simple `cat /etc/motd` kind of autostart.

Comment: Where it displays that? If you're running something (editor, for example) on your screen/byobu/..., how it should display contents of motd?

Comment: I guess you're right. Maybe that task would have to be done by the shell I'm running.

Comment: So you want that to happen every time you open a new shell? For example, new tab on screen, or before screen is reattached? (Something like "press enter to continue")

Comment: Before screen is reattached would do the job.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/connect-to-byobu-screen-session-and-execute-command/5547#5547

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to execute commands, not on reattaching but on idle:
first I changed the byobu backend to screen, then I created a .screenrc in ~/.byobu containing

```
blankerprg  zsh -c "while true; do run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d; sleep 30; clear; done"
idle        600 blanker
```

That uses screen's screensaver functionality to display text I would normally only see on login.